# Floating point number to decimal number

Tags: floating-point, decimal

I have the following floating point number: 1|011|1001. The possible answers in the multiple choice are:
a)-729
b)729
c)72
d)-72. 
 The answer is d) -72. But how is it possible? I have no clue how they calculated this. I think my school uses another method than what is known in the internet, because when I try it like in all those tutorials i have seen, it doesn't work. I even tried it backwards like -72 to floating point but the exponent already would be different. Can someone explain ist for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In “1|011|1001”, 1 is the sign field, 011 is the exponent field, and 1001 is the significand field.

The sign bit is 0 for +, 1 for −, so this is −.

011<sub>2</sub> is 3, apparently meaning scaling by 2<sup>3</sup>

1001<sub>2</sub> is 9, meaning a significand of 9.

So the number is − 2<sup>3</sup> • 9 = −72.

However, this is not at all a standard format. Usually the exponent is biased (offset) by some value. This is commonly 2<sup>*n*−1</sup>−1 for an *n*-bit field, so the bias would be 3 for a 3-bit field, and 001 would represent an exponent of −2, 010 would represent −1, 011 would represent 0, and so on.

Additionally, the significand field is usually scaled, so that 1001 would represent .1001<sub>2</sub> (9/16) rather than 1001<sub>2</sub> (9). Also, the significand is usually formed with a leading bit that is 0 or 1 depending on the value of the exponent field.

So this format is very different from common formats. No test or exercise should expect a student to know it without having documented it previously.

Comment: @EricPostipischil Thank you very much again. Could it then be, that my question from yesterday, that you also answered, has also a different solution? Because so far we didn't even learn about the bias or the special case infinity/NaN. I only did because of you, but now I seeing they dont use the standard format I think it might be different. We also got an e-mail that we need to find a floating point number that can represent 65536 = 2^16. What do you think about that?

Comment: @hexadecimal: Yes, if this school is using some non-standard format, 65536 could be representable in it. You should ask the instructors for a clear specification of the format.

Comment: A good and [patient](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-patience-of-a-saint) answer.